# Where to get the latest opensolaris

Tags: unix, opensolaris

I could find the [wiki page which is telling about opensolaris os](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris) is containing [official site link](http://blog.illumos.org/about-illumos-2/) which does not contain opensolaris download thread etc. Moreover, there is no more [opensolaris official](http://opensolaris.org) site [as said here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris) ;  The http://opensolaris.org redirects to https://solaris.java.net/ only.

So my question is ... does the opensolaris still exist? Where to download the latest version from a safe download center?

Comment: According to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris), OpenSolaris **was** on open source computer operating system... and in 2010 Oracle decided to discontinue. Some folks have forked it under the name [OpenIndiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenIndiana).

Comment: I heard it is no longer developed by oracle; But I am interested in the latest opensolaris release; it should be somewhere anyway though it is old or how you call it... I could see links where opensolaris can be downloaded which are not related to oracle official site but I cannot be sure the links provide the original opensolaris os? So I am asking is there some safe download center(s) for opensolaris which may be still be sponsored by oracle or oracle's partners or something this way so I can be sure it is the original os distribution?

Comment: Why not just use the official Solaris ?  You are free to use it for the purpose of "developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your applications", otherwise you'll have to pay.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of illumos(opensolaris) based distros. omnios, opensxce, openindiana. I like openindiana because it is the closest to opensolaris. I am not sure how things have changed, but i use it now cleanly with nvidia.

Comment: sounds good. thanks :) so you use illumos; could you tell are all the mentioned distros support nVidia?

Comment: I use openindiana but the code base is very similar for all http://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/Graphics+Adapters

Answer (score 0):

No, OpenSolaris no longer exists.  The final release of the OpenSolaris distro was 5 years ago, OpenSolaris 2009.06, and bug fixes & security fixes are no longer available for it.

After the Oracle acquisition, OpenSolaris forked - Oracle continued developing the code and released new versions under a closed-source license as [Solaris 11](http://www.oracle.com/solaris), while the [illumos community](http://www.illumos.org/) took the open source code base and developed it further themselves, generating [a variety of different distros](http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Distributions). Which you use depends on what you want/need from an OS, but there is no single distro that is an exact match for what OpenSolaris was.

Comment: But Solaris 11 etc it is "not-free" for commercial use :P So the illumos "opensolaris" is more handy as I may get it (correct me if I am wrong here pls); Well actually I am not really familiar with illumos distros but I may say I am interested in OS with which I can use as "windows xp pro" for example :S Can you advise what unix based os should I look for?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to really help - if "use as windows xp pro" means you can use ten year old hardware and run old windows apps, then I don't know of any current free Unix-like OS to do that.

Comment: As I can remember the latest solaris was 2009.06 or so; So it is 5 years :) I am not about to run windows apps but I mean OS functionality... Something simple as a) internet ppp support; b) latest jre support; c) 64-bit support d) nVidia support etc a common client machine stuff btw I heard linux has problems with nVidia so I am interested to know does solaris has the same "nVidia" problems?